How to build a monitor that listens to swaps from 100+ wallets?
Question is in the title. I want the most effecient way of doing it, i bought a dedicated node from Helius but unsure how to use gRPC to listen to transactions from a large group of wallets. I know using websockets and webhooks is a lot slower.

One of the ways could be to use Geyser plugin. Not sure if you can do this on a Helius dedicated node though.

Can you elaborate? Do you have a code refernece i can look at?
